# Import sys not getting imported when given inside a function [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7

*generic_import.py*

```
def var_import():
  import sys
  import glob
```

*main.py*

```
from generic_import import *
var_import()
```

whenever I run the main file, I get

NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

However when import sys is outside the function,the code is executed without any error.

generic_import.py

```
import sys
def var_import():
   import glob
```

What's the reason behind this ? I want to import it inside the fucnction.

Comment: Both `sys` and `glob` exists only in local function scope. Any reason you're trying to do that?

Comment: I want them to be used locally to make it more specific, I do not want them globally.

Comment: What do you mean by use them locally. If you use them in `var_import()` directly it shouldn't be any issue. Could you add an example of the usage?

Comment: The var_import() function will have imports that are to be used only when the function is called from the main file. I've added example snippets in the question. If I am putting the import outside the function, the code works perfectly.

Comment: I can't replicate this with python2.7 or python3

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?  What you have should work fine unless you're trying to call `sys` somewhere else.

Comment: You may also want to look at [PEP8 python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) -- both imports in functions and `from x import *` imports are discouraged.

Comment: I think you quite not understand Python internals. All used modules still need to be interpreted, module objects still needs to be put in `sys.modules` (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache). There is basically no profit in doing what you trying to do. Do you really want to remove two names from your global scope and think it's somehow profitable?

Comment: @Rogalski I disagree. Sometime this can be useful. But definitely I think guess OP is trying to use `sys` after calling `var_import`

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use sys after calling var_import and I am puzzled as to why it isn't working.

Comment: @user3100115 sure, I did it once or twice myself, but one should do it only if is aware of what exactly happens here. What are the odds a beginner really needs it?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is the [Scope](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) of the Imports.

You are importing the libraries inside a function so the scope of these is `var_import` and as soon as the function terminates the scope is discarded. You would need to `return` the imported libraries and then save them inside the scope you want to use them.

But I would recommend just `import` libraries as needed without any `generic_import` functionality.

If you are worried about namespace conflicts: You can always use aliases like `import sys as python_builtin_sys` but I wouldn't recommend this either.

---

Since you asked about how to get the modules outside the function scope I'll provide a short example code.

```
def var_import():
    import sys
    import glob
    return sys, glob
```

and you can get them into your wanted scope by using something along the lines of:

```
from generic_import import var_import  # Do not use "import *"
sys, glob = var_import()
```

or something more advanced if you don't know the number of loaded modules.